# Bootstrap form looks odd if multiple <form> tags exits but only one </form> end tag exits

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having this dilemma where my client wants me to have multiple forms on the same page. So what I've come up with is this:

- 2x `<row></row>` tags
- nested in first one are two `<div class="col-md-6"></div>`
- nested in the second are three `<div class="col-md-4"></div>`

The problem is that I have multiple `<form>` tags for each of those `div`s but only one `</form>` right before the submission button. However, it makes the the last four form sections all wobbly unless I add closing form tags. But once I do that, it only lets me submit data from the last div, which I don't want obviously, and the client wants to have five forms that "look" detached from each other.

At the moment the only Bootstrap functionality I can think of that allows me to do that is having different divs with their own forms. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Can you add a plunkr or other example code site to minimize effort to duplicate the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't nest `form`s. The HTML parser will ignore the second `<form>` start tag. So don't do that.

What you *can* do is have multiple forms and associate form controls with the right form using the `form` attribute.

```
<form id=foo><p><input name=foo-a></p></form>
<form id=bar><p><input name=bar-a></p></form>
<p><input name=foo-b form=foo></p>
```